# Bootstrap v2.3.2 Column size edit

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, prestashop

I have a theme in prestashop that use Bootstrap v2.3.2 and Bootstrap Responsive v2.3.2. 
My layout have an Header, 3 columns (left, center, right) and a footer. 
I have hide the right column.

I have a margin-left before the left column and a margin-right before the center column that I'd like to edit, it change size in "% i think" for the size of device screen. 
I want the left column (with the same size) more near the margin left, and the center column (more large) near the margin right

What i have to edit?
Thank you so much

Comment: Are you able to provide some code? Or can you F12 to open web developer tools in Chrome and inspect the markup with corresponding css? Also I'm not entirely sure what you trying to achieve - what means "left column more near the margin left..."?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not too sure what you would like to do but I recommend reading about the fluid grid system in Boostrap 2.3 http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html

HTML

```
<div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="span4 column1">...</div>
  <div class="span4 column2">...</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.comlumn1 {
 margin-left:your spacing;
 margin-right:your spacing;
}

.comlumn2 {
 margin-left:your spacing;
 margin-right:your spacing;
}
```

In order to get the sizing you want you may want to use bigger span size. Span 1 - 12

Answer (score 0):

url https://luxelumi.com/

add it to url --> css/2/bootstrap.css
add it to url --> css/2/bootstrap-responsive.css

how to change layout: add it to url --> themes/theme784/img/bootstrap.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Solved: 
bootstrap.css

.container,
.navbar-static-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-top .container,
.navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
  **width: 1250px;**
}

.span9 {
  **width: 1000px;**
}

in product-list.tpl
{assign var='nbItemsPerLine' value=3}

chage to

**{assign var='nbItemsPerLine' value=4}**